# Smtplib code working in python3.7 for linux but not for windows 10

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send automated mail through outlook using python3.7.The smtlib code is working fine for python installed in linux while the same code is returning me error for windows.

```
import time, os, smtplib
from datetime import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders


print("sam")
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
print("sam1")
s.starttls()
print("sam2")
s.login("samgupta@xyz.com", "Welcome")
message = "Hi"
print("sam3")
s.sendmail("samgupta@xyz.com", "abc@xyz.com", message)
s.quit()
```

This is the error message i am getting in windows python :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/sysadmin/Desktop/mail.py", line 10, in 
>       s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)   File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 251, in **init**
>       (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)   File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 336, in connect
>       self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)   File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 307, in _get_socket
>       self.source_address)   File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py",
>   line 727, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py",
>   line 716, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond

Comment: This appears to be a network issues. Do yo have any proxies in between? Check if any firewall rules holding back your connect requests. do telnet <host> 587, traceroute etc to troubleshoot network issues.

Comment: I am using same network for linux code also and there it is working !

Comment: It seems that there is a problem in the TLS handshake. Have you given right certs and right location? Also, you are using starttls(), which is not recommanded in 3.7. Try using SMTP_SSL, and put the connect code in try block and see what is the exception it throws.

Comment: Also, before s.login() call, there supposed to be EHLO or HELO call. Try the same. Please check this link, https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this bit? This should print the exceptions and we can fix the problem once we know the problem nature.

```
import smtplib
global server
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL( < host >, < port >)
    except Exception as e:
    print("{}".format(e))

try:
    server.login("your username", "your password")
except Exception as e:
    print("{}".format(e))
server.sendmail(
    "from@address.com",
    "to@address.com",
    "this message is from python")
server.quit()
```

Comment: Getting this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\mail.py", line 31, in <module>
    server.sendmail(
NameError: name 'server' is not defined

Comment: Try making server a global. "Global server". Check the edit bit above.